# Updating one table row with information from multiple rows in different table

Tags: mysql

I have searched quite a lot but haven´t found a solution to my problem. Now I hope someone can help me here.

I have two tables in an MySQL database and both tables have the columns **Name** and **ArticleID**

What I would like to do is to copy the content in the column Name from Table 1 to Table 2 where the ArticleID match. All the names should be separated by a comma in the column Name in Table 2.

In Table 1 there are for example 3 rows with the same content in the column Name but each row has a unique ArticleID. In 3 other rows there are a different Name but the ArticleID´s is the same as the first 3 rows.

**Table 1**

```
Name 1 - 1
Name 2 - 2
Name 3 - 3
Name 4 - 1
Name 5 - 2
Name 6 - 3
```

**Table 2**

```
1 - Name 1, Name 4
2 - Name 2, Name 5
3 - Name 3, Name 6
```

This would not normally be a problem for me, But now there are multiple rows with the same ArticleID and i can´t seem to figure it out by my self.

I hope you understand what I want :-)

Melker

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2(id, names)
SELECT ArticleID, GROUP_CONCAT(Name) 
FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY ArticleID;
```

Comment: have a try and let us know :)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE 
    TABLE2 
JOIN (SELECT ArticleID, GROUP_CONCAT(Name) AS Name FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY ArticleID) TABLE1
ON TABLE2.ArticleID = TABLE1.ArticleID
SET TABLE2.Name = TABLE1.Name
WHERE TABLE2.ArticleID = TABLE1.ArticleID
```

I actually had to use UPDATE and this worked